# Storing Application State in MongoDB vs S3 as JSON

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-s3, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am making a meteor app using Mobx-State-tree , graphql and Mongo DB.

In the app, there is a section called courses which has chapters which in turn has topics.

The Course Section state is managed by a CourseModel using mobx-state-tree. 
So, any user that starts a course has his state managed by the CourseModel. I am taking the snapshot of the CourseModel as JSON and would like to restore the state using the apply snapshot of Mobx. The JSON file generated is in bytes. Pretty small. But I expect a lot of users and don't want to give additional load on the MongoDB.

The issue is where to keep the snapshot?

Option 1: I can store it in the S3 and when the user goes to the course, the json is downloaded and then applied.

Option 2: I can store snapshot directly in the MongoDB Collection.

Which one do you suggest?

Comment: I'd say go with Mongo. You are already using it as the DB solution, adding another level of complexity would bring more problems than solutions. Also, Mongo can handle pretty well A LOT of data

Comment: Thanks for answering. I started using MongoDB. And you are correct, it is way easier to sync it.